# login and signup screens can't present or dismiss

Tags: firebase, xcode9, swift4.1

okay I need help I'm trying to present the loginController that users have to sign up or login before they can use app but I can't get it to present I don't what to do anymore I try everything

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()

    self.title = "Messages"

    let btnMenu = UIBarButtonItem(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "menu"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(btnMenuAction))
    btnMenu.tintColor=UIColor(red: 54/255, green: 55/255, blue: 56/255, alpha: 1.0)
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = btnMenu

    sidebarView=SidebarView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: self.view.frame.height))
    sidebarView.delegate=self
    sidebarView.layer.zPosition=100
    self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled=true
    self.navigationController?.view.addSubview(sidebarView)

    blackScreen=UIView(frame: self.view.bounds)
    blackScreen.backgroundColor=UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.5)
    blackScreen.isHidden=true
    self.navigationController?.view.addSubview(blackScreen)
    blackScreen.layer.zPosition=99
    let tapGestRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(blackScreenTapAction(sender:)))
    blackScreen.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestRecognizer)

    if Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid == nil {
        handleSignOut()

        //what happens? we need to present some kind of login controller
        perform(#selector(handleSignOut), with: nil, afterDelay: 0)
    }

  //  let loginController = LoginController()
   // self.present(loginController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@objc func handleSignOut() {

    do {
    try Auth.auth().signOut()
    } catch let logoutError {
        print(logoutError)
    }

    let loginController = LoginController()
    self.present(loginController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

this is for the login button this is the login button won't dismiss the login screen when you login thanks for the help

```
let loginRegisterButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)

    button.backgroundColor = UIColor(r: 80, g: 101, b: 161)
    button.setTitle("Register", for: .normal)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 9
    button.layer.masksToBounds = true

    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleLoginRegister), for: .touchUpInside)

    return button

}()

@objc func handleLoginRegister() {
    if loginRegisterSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        handleLogin()
    } else {
        handleRegister()
    }
}

func handleLogin() {
    guard let email = emailTextField.text, !email.isEmpty else { return }
    guard let password = passwordTextField.text, !password.isEmpty else { return }
    print("Form is not valid")

    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (user, err) in


        if let err = err {
            print("Failed to sign in with email:", err)
            return
        }
        print("Successfully logged back in with user:", user?.user.uid ?? "")


        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)


    })


}
```

Comment: Does it give you "Failed to sign in" when you login?

Comment: No it will login but it won’t dismiss

Comment: What is the launcher controller in your app (Login or .....)?

Comment: it viewController

Comment: You want me post it

Comment: The first code that you post is for what controller?

Comment: The top code is for the view controller and the bottom code is for the login and register view controller

Comment: Does the register works?

Comment: Yes it work it will put user in the Database and it will login it just won’t dismiss and present if you need more code I can add more code if you need it